# Exception thrown when setting DataGridView property

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView table that displays the properties of EmployeeModels.  When compiling, this exception is thrown:
`'ColumnCount property cannot be set on a data-bound DataGridView control.'`

I have heard that setting `.Datasource = null` before binding to the actual list can help, but doing so has not resolved the issue.  I tried deleting the DataGridView and recreating it in case there was a bug, but this didn't resolve the issue.

```
                //CREATE EMPLOYEE TABLE
                public void CreateEmployeeTable()
                {
                    EmployeeGridView.DataSource = null;
                    EmployeeGridView.DataSource = globalEmployeeList;
                    EmployeeGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                    EmployeeGridView.ColumnCount = 9;
                    EmployeeGridView.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Employee ID";
                    EmployeeGridView.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "ID";
                    EmployeeGridView.Columns[1].HeaderText = "First Name";
                    EmployeeGridView.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "FirstName";
                    EmployeeGridView.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Last Name";
                    EmployeeGridView.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "LastName";
                    EmployeeGridView.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Nickname";
                    EmployeeGridView.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "Nickname";
                    EmployeeGridView.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Hire Date";
                    EmployeeGridView.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = "HireDate";
                }

        private void EmployeeGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewCell selectedEmployeeCell = EmployeeGridView.CurrentCell;
            int selectedEmployeeRow = selectedEmployeeCell.RowIndex;
            int selectedEmployeeID = (int)EmployeeGridView.Rows[selectedEmployeeRow].Cells[0].Value;
            jobTitleListBox.DataSource = globalEmployeeList.Where(person => person.ID == selectedEmployeeID).ToList();
        }
```

Here is the SQL (And yes, I'm going to make this a stored procedure eventually; I'm just not there yet.)

```
       public async Task<List<EmployeeModel>> GetEmployeeList()
        {
            using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(GlobalConfig.CnnString("WorkDeskDB")))
            {
                var sql = @"SELECT e.id, e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.Nickname, 
                                   em.EmployeeID, em.Address, em.Type, 
                                   e.JobTitleID, jt.id, jt.Name, 
                                   p.EmployeeID, p.Number, p.Type,
                                   ect.EmployeeID, ect.NameID, ect.InitialDate, ect.ExpirationDate,
                                   ct.id, ct.Name
                          
                          FROM dbo.Employees e 
                          LEFT JOIN dbo.Emails em
                          ON em.EmployeeID = e.id
                          LEFT JOIN dbo.JobTitles jt  
                          ON e.JobTitleID = jt.id
                          LEFT JOIN Phones p
                          ON p.EmployeeID = e.id
                          LEFT JOIN dbo.EmployeeCertificationType ect
                          ON ect.EmployeeID = e.id
                          LEFT JOIN dbo.CertificationType ct
                          ON ect.NameID = ct.id"; 

                var employees = await connection.QueryAsync<EmployeeModel, EmailModel, TitleModel, PhoneModel, CertificationModel, EmployeeModel>(sql, (e, em, t, p, c) =>
                {
                    e.EmailList.Add(em);
                    e.JobTitle = t;
                    e.PhoneList.Add(p);
                    e.CertificationList.Add(c);
                    return e;
                }, splitOn: "EmployeeID, JobTitleID, EmployeeID, EmployeeID");

                var result = employees.GroupBy(e => e.ID).Select(g =>
                {
                    var groupedEmployee = g.First();
                    groupedEmployee.EmailList = g.Select(e => e.EmailList.Single()).ToList();
                    groupedEmployee.PhoneList = g.Select(e => e.PhoneList.Single()).ToList();
                    groupedEmployee.CertificationList = g.Select(e => e.CertificationList.Single()).ToList();
                    return groupedEmployee;
                });
                return result.ToList();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why are you setting the `ColumnCount`, you should just remove columns you don't need after data-binding, or set `AutoGenerateColumns = false` and create each column manually

Comment: Did you try binding the list to a `BindingSource` and use this as source for the `DataGridView.DataSource`? [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource?view=net-5.0) states this as a go to method to resolve a lot of binding issues.

Comment: The error is clear... [DataGridView.ColumnCount Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columncount?view=net-5.0) … “Exceptions”… _”InvalidOperationException”_ … “_When setting this property, the DataSource property has been set.”_ …. I will assume this is the error. Comment out the code and set the columns you don’t want to show as `Visible = false.` Or add the columns manually as commented already.

Comment: While you can't set the columncount directly (up or down) you can stll __add__  (and __remove__) columns in the DGV!

Comment: In the code I posted, I do set .AutoGenerateColumns = false, and I go on to add the columns manually.  I've deleted the .ColumnCount declaration, so I no longer receive that error; however, at runtime the datagridview is still autogenerating the columns.  For instance, I end up with two columns for Hire Date.

Comment: _In the code I posted, I do set .AutoGenerateColumns = false, and I go on to add the columns manually. ..._ If you are adding additional columns at runtime, then you need to remove them. The `EmployeeGridView.DataSource = null;` won't. So, you also need to call `EmployeeGridView.Columns.Clear();` before resetting the `DataSource`. Right after the first line. Note, you will need to add those additional columns again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, no, you should never ever fiddle with the cells that display your data.

Or in other words: separate your data from how it is displayed. Apart from that your code will be easier to read, it will also be easier to change. What, if for instance you want to display your data in a ListView, or maybe as a Graph.

Separating your data from how it is displayed also makes it easier to reuse it, to change the data and to test it.

### Fetch the Employees

So, assuming you know your SQL, the following should be no problem.

(I leave out all the async-await stuff, that is not part of your problem).

```
private IEnumerable<Employee> FetchEmployees()
{
    // TODO: implement, fetch employees from the database
}
```

The nice thing is, that you hid the structure of your database. So if you decide to change the tables of your database, then the users of this method (= code, not operators), won't have to change. They don't even have to change if you decide to save the data in an XML file, or in a Dictionary. The latter might be quite handy if you need to unit test your code: you don't have to fill a database for every test, a dictionary with Employees will do.

### Display the Fetched Employees

So let's assume you have a method to fetch all employees in some smart way.

To display it, you could fiddle with the cells. But a much nice method would be to use the `DataSource` of the `DatagridView`

Suppose your Employees have properties Id and Name, and several others. You want to show your Employees row by row, and you want to show properties Id and Name as columns:

```
DataGridViewColumn columnEmployeeId  new DataGridViewColumn();
DataGridViewColumn columnEmployeeName  new DataGridViewColumn();
columnEmployeeId.DataPropertyName = nameof(Employee.Id);    
columnEmployeeName.DataPropertyName = nameof(Employee.Name);
```

Property DataPropertyName contains the name of the property that it should show.

Now all you have to do is Fetch the employees, and assign them to the DataSource of the DataGridView:

```
var employees = this.FetchEmployees().ToList();
this.DatagridView1.DataSource = employees;
```

This is enough display your employees. Changes that the operator makes to the displayed data are not updated in object employees. If you want that, you should put your data in an object that implements `IBindingList`, like `BindingList<T>`

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingList<Employee>(FetchEmployees().ToList());
```

Now every change that the operator makes to the displayed Employees are automatically updated in the BindingList. Even if he adds or removes Employees.

The BindingList does not depend on how the data is displayed. So if you decide not to display column Id anymore, or if you decide to sort the displayed data by descending Name, this has no effect on the BindingList. If you look closely, you'll see that the BindingList in fact is not a List, but a Collection. There is no notion of `Employee[3]`. This is expected, because if the operator sorts the displayed data, this Employee might not be shown in the Row[3] anymore.

Proper design of your form would contain methods like:

```
IEnumerable<Employee> FetchEmployees() {... see above}

BindingList<Employee> DisplayedEmployees
{
    get => (BindingList<Employee>)this.dataGridView1.DataSource;
    set => this.dataGridView1.DataSource = value;
}

Employee CurrentEmployee =>
   (Employee) this.datagridView1.SelectedCell?.OwningRow.DataBoundItem;

IEnumerable<Employee> SelectedEmployees =>
    this.DatagridView1.SelectedRows
        .Select(row => row.DataBoundItem)
        .Cast<Employee>();
```

Putting it all together:

On form load: display all employees:

```
void Form_Load(object sender, ...)
{
    this.DisplayedEmployees = this.FetchEmployees();
}
```

After ButtonRemoveClicked: remove all Selected Employees:

```
void ButtonRemove_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    void employeestoRemove = SelectedEmployees.ToList();
    if (employeesToRemove.Any())
    {
        // TODO: ask operator if remove employees is ok
        this.Repository.RemoveEmployees(employeesToRemove);
    }
}
```

After an edit, all items in the datasource are updated:

```
void OnButtonOk_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    var displayedEmployees = this.DisplayedEmployees;
    var originalEmployees = this.FetchEmployees;

    // TODO: find out which employees were added / removed / changed
    // and Add / Remove / Update the data
}
```

### Conclusion

Because you separated the handling of the database from the display of the employees the procedures are much smaller, easier to understand, easier to reuse, test, change.

Your code doesn't have to worry about sorting, column reordening, change in how data is displayed (is Birthday displayed as month-day-year, or as 2021-01-15?), your Form class does not have to worry about this, and does not need big changes if this is changed.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time.  How do I define the new column's relationship to EmployeeGridView?  I could create just those columns I need, but what says they belong to EmployeeGridView?

I implemented your directions, and the table auto-generated all of the columns returned by the query.

 `public void CreateEmployeeTable()
        {      
            DataGridViewColumn employeeIDColumn = new DataGridViewColumn();
            employeeIDColumn.DataPropertyName = "EmployeeID";
            EmployeeGridView.DataSource = globalEmployeeList;
         }
`
Have I lost the plot?

Comment: Create a playground forrms solution. Give it a DataGridView and some columns. Look in InitializeComponent to the created code and see how the columns are attached to the DataGridView. I left this out, because this standard code would only clutter my example with code of which I assumed you investigated already before asking questions